# Woocommerce Add custom "Add to cart button" in single page with tags

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to add a custom "ADD TO CART" button in the single product page.

I have done it using the id of the product.

```
<?php echo '<a href="?add-to-cart='.get_the_id($product_id).'">ADD TO CART</a>'; ?>
```

I want to add quantity, variation and attribute tags too.

so that I can get sth like:

```
domain.com/myproduct/?add-to-cart=100&variation_id=200&attribute_pa_colour=blue
```

Comment: please check url :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322538/custom-add-to-cart-button-link-in-variable-single-product-pages

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have already checked it but it does not work for my example. I need to add the tags in the above link where I have already achieved to use the id tag.